# Changing row values based on previous row values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
Province              Admissions
Eastern Cape          10
Private               3
Public                7
Free State            20
Private               15 
Public                5
```

I want to change the 'Private' and 'Public' to reference the Province. I want to achieve the following dataframe:

```
Province               Admissions
Eastern Cape           10
Eastern Cape-Private   3
Eastern Cape-Public    7
Free State             20
Free State-Private     15 
Free State-Public      5
```

I've actually already achieved this by the following code:

```
for row in range(0,len(df)):
    df['Province'] = np.where((df['Province'] == 'Private'), df['Province'].shift(1)+' '+ df['Province'], df['Province'])
    df['Province'] = np.where((df['Province'] == 'Public'), df['Province'].shift(2)+' '+ df['Province'], df['Province'])
```

However, I would like to do it in a more general approach, in case the order of the Private and Public is swapped. Right now Private comes before Public hence my method workds. Would appreciate any input!

Comment: a perhaps slightly more general solution would be when you have 'public' or 'private' then do a `.shift(1)` and if that is 'public' or 'private' do a `.shift(2)` else just keep the `.shift(1)`.

Comment: Is it always a triplet of `(Place, Private, Public)` (or private and public swapped)?

Comment: hmmmm did  you try that on a pivot table? it seems like to be much cleaner in a pivot table.

Comment: First question I would ask is why `for row in range(0,len(df)):`? Other than that, your two `np.where` would work fine with you use case.

Answer (score 2):

You can do `mask` and `ffill` create the adding array

```
s = df.Province.mask(df.Province.isin(['Private','Public'])).ffill()
df['Province'] = np.where(df.Province.isin(['Private','Public']), s + ' ' + df.Province, df.Province)
```

Comment: I was going for same approach, except that I cache `df.Province.isin`.